# UnityEngine Video3DLayout.SideBySide3D code not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm new to C# and Unity, but I'm trying to code an app with Unity which would play my customer's 3D Side by Side VR video. I'm using script from here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html to get the video running and it works great, BUT it doesn't play as Side By Side VR video, but just a flat video with two screens for both eyes.

UnityEngine.Video has Video3DLayout.SideBySide3d enumeration (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.Video3DLayout.html) that could solve the problem, but I don't know what is the right syntax for that. Here is the code I have tried:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movie : MonoBehaviour{

    enum Video3DLayout {No3D, SideBySide3D, OverUnder3D};

    void Start(){

        Video3DLayout myLayout;
        myLayout = Video3DLayout.SideBySide3D;

        // Will attach a VideoPlayer to the main camera.
        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");

        // VideoPlayer automatically targets the camera backplane when it is added
        // to a camera object, no need to change videoPlayer.targetCamera.
        var videoPlayer = camera.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();

        // Play on awake defaults to true. Set it to false to avoid the url set
        // below to auto-start playback since we're in Start().
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;

        // By default, VideoPlayers added to a camera will use the far plane.
        // Let's target the near plane instead.
        videoPlayer.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.CameraNearPlane;

        // Set the video to play.
        videoPlayer.url = "movie.mp4";        

        // Start playback. This means the VideoPlayer may have to prepare (reserve
        // resources, pre-load a few frames, etc.). To better control the delays
        // associated with this preparation one can use videoPlayer.Prepare() along with
        // its prepareCompleted event.
        videoPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

I have feeling that I'm introducing the enumerations wrong way and I hope that someone could guide me to right direction. I have tried to use this tutorial https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/enumerations to understand more about enumerations, but this way my code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 reasons why it isn't working. You're creating a new enum, instead of using the UnityEngine.Video.Video3DLayout enum. Also you're not assigning myLayout to the videoPlayer.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class Movie : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Video3DLayout myLayout;

    void Start()
    {
        // Will attach a VideoPlayer to the main camera.
        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");

        // VideoPlayer automatically targets the camera backplane when it is added
        // to a camera object, no need to change videoPlayer.targetCamera.
        var videoPlayer = camera.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
        videoPlayer.targetCamera3DLayout = myLayout;

        // Play on awake defaults to true. Set it to false to avoid the url set
        // below to auto-start playback since we're in Start().
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;

        // By default, VideoPlayers added to a camera will use the far plane.
        // Let's target the near plane instead.
        videoPlayer.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.CameraNearPlane;

        // Set the video to play.
        videoPlayer.url = "movie.mp4";

        // Start playback. This means the VideoPlayer may have to prepare (reserve
        // resources, pre-load a few frames, etc.). To better control the delays
        // associated with this preparation one can use videoPlayer.Prepare() along with
        // its prepareCompleted event.
        videoPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Miikka for help! This did the trick and helped me a lot.